# iOS Chat Messaging App - Send/Receive Message & Notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, chat

I am building application for chatting. As it is a chatting app, so the messages got to be real quick. Web services are ready and web service sends message notification and I got to act accordingly on the application. API sends notifications & android version  uses GCM to achieve the same. Socket IO is used for developing the server side.

My concerns are :- I can use APNS to get the notifications. BUT is usage of APNS reliable for such an application.

On many sites I have read - APNS is just for sending notifications & not direct messaging & many other factors of it. On many sites/comments I also read that If is fast & reliable, developers have used it successfully in their messaging systems.

Can you please help me know the facts - Is it appropriate for chatting application ? What are the other alternative or better solutions. When more people will be chatting, will that affect the APNS or so..

New API's will be designed based on my needs - so am not stuck to using a single pattern.
Need your guidance to decide to opt the right technology to use. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `API uses GCM to sent notifications.` i didnt get this.

Comment: I mean - API sends notifications & android version uses GCM to achieve the same. Is it now clear to understand and guide me with same.

Comment: IIRC, GCM has similar non-reliability properties to APNS. I'd suggest not depending on either for the real-time chatting, only for notifications when the user isn't inside the app.

Answer (score 1):

APNs are not reliable as doc says.
I can suggest to use socket connection for chat purposes. I've implement it in my last application and it works very well.
I've used CFNetwork API for persistent connections:

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)kServerIP, kServerPort,     &readStream, &writeStream);
self.inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
self.outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

//Add streams to run loop
[self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.inputStream open];
[self.outputStream open];

//Then handle NSStream delegates for in/out messages
```

...And also you can use APNs to notify user while in lock screen.

Comment: Thanks. As you have mentioned using socket connection, I would like to tell - WS uses socketIO for server side development. Can I use the same or incase this info helps you help me in any ways.

Comment: Yes, you can use NSStream for Websockets as well. I can also suggest great open source lib called SocketRocket to make you life easier with WS.
https://github.com/square/SocketRocket.

Comment: Thanks Krivoblotsky. While studying on the same, I also found SocketRocket & found it useful too. My last concern regarding this - Using CFStream or SocketRocket (socket.io) does performance and reliability affects. I mean Performance, Reliability & Speed wise which will be better in compare to both of them. And in compare with APNS too i.e. APNS vs Socket for this matter. Your guidance has helped me select the path, now just need to choose from these two.

Comment: I copied all 7 files from square/SocketRocket/SocketRocket group in a new group named "SocketRocket" in my application. I added CFNetwork.framework in Linker setting of the prom. On Clean & Build, I get 2 Apple Mach-O Linker errors & 1 warning. Linker Err - Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody", referenced from:
      _validate_dispatch_data_partial_string in SRWebSocket.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)  Can you help to get rid of them. How I add socket.io in my app ???